# Users with read only permissions can't see custom Master Page and Managed Metadata Navigation SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, security-trimming, term

Managed Metadata Navigation not working for  Users with read permission in SharePoint 2013 if I give target url as  `/Forms/AllItems.aspx` or `blog/default.aspx`,  the term itself is not visible in the navigation tree.

Please help me out of this issue.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does all the terms has an associated page?

Comment: Yes...we are using term driven friendly url..not simple link url..  Please reply if you have any input on this.

Comment: Those will get security trimmed if the user dont have permissions to those page.

Comment: But even though the user having read permission to list , if we give list/form/allitem.Aspx the term itself not appearing on the navigation tree.. For users having read permission only we are having this issue..

Comment: Check if the user can open the allitem.aspx without any issues. Navigation is security trimmed, if the term has not associated page or the user has no permission to that page then the term will not be visible.

Comment: Check to see if the target page for the term is expired.

Comment: Hi @Chad, Welcome to SE community, we have converted your answer to a comment because it's flagged as a Low-Quality Answer, So, please try to add more details in your answer to be very clear and helpful, thank you for your contributions!